# OOP way to implement class for comparison in Python

Tags: python, matching, readability

Using Python, I am trying to implement a set of types including a "don't care" type, for fuzzy matching.  I have implemented it like so:

```
class Matchable(object):        
    def __init__(self, match_type = 'DEFAULT'):
        self.match_type = match_type

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.match_type == 'DONTCARE' or other.match_type == 'DONTCARE' \
or self.match_type == other.match_type)
```

Coming from an OO background, this solution seems inelegant; using the Matchable class results in ugly code.  I'd prefer to eliminate match_type, and instead make each type its own class inherited from a superclass, then use type checking to do the comparisons.  However type checking appears to be generally frowned upon:

http://www.canonical.org/~kragen/isinstance/

Is there are better (more pythonic) way to implement this functionality?

**Note:** I'm aware of the large number of questions and answers about Python "enums", and it may be that one of those answers is appropriate.  The requirement for the overridden __ eq __ function complicates matters, and I haven't seen a way to use the proposed enum implementations for this case.

The best OO way I can come up with of doing this is:

```
class Match(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(self, DontCare) or isinstance(other, DontCare) or type(self) == type(other)

class DontCare(Match):
    pass

class A(Match):
    pass

class B(Match):
    pass

d = DontCare()
a = A()
b = B()


print d == a
True
print a == d
True
print d == b
True
print a == b
False
print d == 1
True
print a == 1
False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you linked says that `isinstance` isn't always evil, and I think in your case it is appropriate. The main complaint in the article is that using `isinstance` to check whether an object supports a particular interface reduces opportunities to use implied interfaces, and it's a fair point. In your case, however, you would essentially be using a `Dontcare` class to provide an annotation for how an object should be treated in comparisons, and `isinstance` would be checking such an annotation, which should be perfectly. fine.

Comment: Agreed.  Personally I think it might be appropriate, but I'm interested to see what more experienced pythonistas think, and whether there's a really elegant solution without using isinstance.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you just need to check if any of the operands is a fuzzy type, no?

```
class Fuzzy(object):
    def __eq__(*args):
        def isFuzzy(obj):
            return isinstance(obj, Fuzzy)
        return any(map(isFuzzy, args))
```

Now you can do:

```
>>> class DefaultClass(object):
...    pass

>>> class DontCareClass(Fuzzy):
...    pass

>>> DefaultClass() == DontCareClass()
True
```

Since we're using `isInstance`, this will work just fine with polymorphism. This is a perfectly legitimate use of `isInstance` in my opinion. What you want to avoid is type checking when you can just rely on duck typing, but this is not one of those cases.

EDIT: Actually, for practical purposes, this would be perfectly fine too:

```
class Fuzzy(object):
    def __eq__(*args):
        return True
```